# How to use the minimum amount of GPU memory needed by the model built in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

After learning how to allocate GPU memory for running models built with TensorFlow, I came to understand that I can:

1. Allocate a fraction of the total memory or,
2. Use `allow_growth` to allocate as much memory as the model needs.

However, it seems that using `allow_growth` does not allocate the minimal amount of memory that the model needs to run successfully.

For example, I've implemented a modified version of PVANet-Lite (~1.2 M parameters) as the backbone for a detection task. When I use `allow_growth`, the program takes up to `~4500MB` memory; but when the memory limit is set to `800MB`, the program still runs successfully with similar detection rate (fps).

So , my questions are:

1. Does TensorFlow have the option to automatically set the memory limit to be as small as the model needs?
2. What might be the cause for the example that I ran into in this case?

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't have any option to set automatically the memory limit, it's going to take all if you don't set a limit.

Comment: From what I understand from the source, `allow_growth` should initially allocate [as little as 1Mb](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.10.1/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc#L38). If that is not the case you may want to file an issue.

Comment: @P-Gn Thanks for the suggestion. I couldn't find any related questions or solutions either